# Are finitely additive Baire measures the same as Radon measures

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory, borel-measures

If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, we know that finite Baire measures uniquely extend to a Radon measure. Furthermore every Radon measure also restricts to a Baire measure. We also know that every tight finitely additive finite Borel measure (i.e. it satisfies inner regularity with respect to compacts, the Radon property) is also countably additive. Is it the case also that every finite finitely additive measure on the Baire $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ uniquely extends to a Radon measure?

Comment: Did you want something like a tightness condition also?  Otherwise, take $X$ to be a countable space, so that every set is both Borel and Baire.  A free ultrafilter on $X$ gives rise to a finitely additive measure on the power set, which is not countably additive.

Comment: Thanks. That does indeed answer my question in the negative, since I didn't intend a regularity condition on the Baire measures. If you leave an answer below happy to mark it as closed, or to delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction between Baire and Borel measures is a red herring.  We can consider a countable space $X$, where the Baire and Borel $\sigma$-algebras are both just the power set, i.e. every subset is both Baire and Borel.  Then the question is just "must a finite, finitely additive measure on the power set also be countably additive"?  And the answer is no, because a free ultrafilter provides a counterexample.

Comment: I guess for completion, I'll just flesh out the argument by noting that, an easy example of a countable compact Hausdorff space where this will fail is the one-point compactification of the naturals. Singletons are closed, and so obviously Borel, and since points can be separated by functions to $[0,1]$, and there are only countably many, all singletons are also Baire.

Comment: @OddlyAsymmetric: Indeed, it works for every countable Hausdorff space.  Singletons are closed, hence Borel, and they are also compact $G_\delta$ sets (since $\{x\} = \bigcap_{y \ne x} \{y\}^c$), hence Baire.